# ASP.NET C# - How to retain value after Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working in ASP.NET c# application.
I came to a part where I need to retain some value after response.redirect to the same page **without using additional QueryString or Session**, because Session more or less may burden the server's performance even just a small value.

Below is my code fragment:

```
 protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
string id = ddl.SelectedValue;
string id2 = ddl2.SelectedValue;
Response.Redirect("http://sharepoint2007/sites/home/Lists/CustomList/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + id);
 }
```

I wanted to retain the value id2 after the Response.Redirect, I've tried ViewState but seem like after the redirect, it treat the page as new page and ViewState value gone.

**Update:**

My intention to retain the value after redirect is wanted to bind back the dropdownlist selected value.

Please help.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using cookies will do the trick:

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = ddl.SelectedValue;
    string id2 = ddl2.SelectedValue;
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("SecondId", id2);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    Response.Redirect("http://sharepoint2007/sites/home/Lists/CustomList/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + id);
}

protected void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id2 = Request.Cookies["SecondId"];
    //send a cookie with an expiration date in the past so the browser deletes the other one
    //you don't want the cookie appearing multiple times on your server
    HttpCookie clearCookie = new HttpCookie("SecondId", null);
    clearCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(clearCookie);
}
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, I though cookies is stored on user's browser? I try not to store the value into server cause there were thousand of users accessing the page, it could encourage performance issue.

Comment: yes the value is stored on the client. In this case you wouldn't have a performance issue. It scales quite well. You should also know that you can store a simple id in the session without having serious performance/scalability problems.

Comment: just wonder is drawback of using cookies? such as any browser setting might prevent storing of data in cookies?

Comment: Cookies can be disabled by the user but this usually doesn't happen unless your clients work in a strict corporate environment. Basically if you turn them off most internet sites stop working, so no normal user has them turned off. If your application is public you shouldn't worry about cookies not working

Answer (score 3):

Make use of **Session** variable will do for you

Code for you

```
Session["id2"] = ddl2.SelectedValue;
```

as you are redirecting from one page to another page viewstate is not going to help you , Session varialbe can able to store value till the user logout of site or till session ends, ViewState is helpfull when you are doing autopostback to your page

or

if possible you can attach id2 variable in **querystring** only as you are doing with id1 variable

Comment: Pranay Rana, thanks for your reply. I do mention due to some concern, I do not wanted to use Session

Comment: @sams5817 - than either go for cookies or make use of querystring

Answer (score 2):

besides session, query string, you can also use cookie, application variable and database to persist your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using **Session** or by **QueryString**

By **Session**

In your first page:

```
Session["abc"] = ddlitem;
```

Then in your next page access the session using:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String cart= String.Empty;
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["abc"].ToString()))
    {
        xyz= Session["abc"].ToString();
        // do Something();
    }
    else
    {
        // do Something();
    }
}
```

-

By **QueryString**

In your first page:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String abc= "ddlitem";
    Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx?ddlitemonnextpage" + abc)
}
```

In your second page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xyz= Request.QueryString["ddlitemonnextpage"].ToString();
    // do Something();
}
```